# How do I add a partition to my Hive table?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, partitioning, partition

I'm creating a table in Hive but unsure of the syntax to add a partition. Here is a simplified version of the create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE sales.newtable AS
SELECT report_date
, SUM(cost_amt) AS cost_amt
, SUM(vendor_revenue_amt) AS vendor_revenue_amt
, SUM(gcr_amt) AS gcr_amt
, first_name
, last_name
, emailhash
FROM bi_reports.datorama_affiliate_mart AS orders
WHERE report_date >= '2019-01-01'
AND data_stream_name <> 'uds_order'
GROUP BY report_date
, first_name
, last_name
, emailhash
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create partitioned table AS SELECT supported only in Hive since  3.2.0, see ([HIVE-20241](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-20241)).

For previous Hive version, create table separately, then load data using `INSERT`.

See manual here: [Create Table As Select (CTAS)](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableCreate/Drop/TruncateTable#Create%20Table%20As%20Select%20(CTAS))

Answer (score 0):

CREATE-TABLE-AS-SELECT does not support partitioning(Not sure about latest version).

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10068]: CREATE-TABLE-AS-SELECT does
>   not support partitioning in the target table

Instead you can create new sales.newtable, But keep in mind partition column should be the last column in you table definition and last column in your insert query as well.

lets say if emailhash is your partition column in table

and then insert

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;

insert overwrite table sales.newtable PARTITION(emailhash)
SELECT report_date
, SUM(cost_amt) AS cost_amt
, SUM(vendor_revenue_amt) AS vendor_revenue_amt
, SUM(gcr_amt) AS gcr_amt
, first_name
, last_name
, emailhash
FROM bi_reports.datorama_affiliate_mart AS orders
WHERE report_date >= '2019-01-01'
AND data_stream_name <> 'uds_order'
GROUP BY report_date
, first_name
, last_name
, emailhash;
```